# Authenticate samba users using AD

Tags: ubuntu, samba, active-directory

So I have an ubuntu 20.04 machine that I want to use as the storage server for my domain using samba. The server is not a DC, but it is joined to the domain as any other computer using `realmd` and `sssd` (I used this guide https://computingforgeeks.com/join-ubuntu-debian-to-active-directory-ad-domain/). And that part works, I can login as a domain user and can see all my user's groups that are set in the windows ad server.
I was trying to make a test directory (everyone can read/write) just to test the connection but I can't get samba to even run. I have tried `passdb backend = ldapsam:\\` and `security = ads` and I can't get it to work: Both crash the `smbd.service`. Here are the logs from both attempts:

```
  pdb backend ldapsam:"ldap://domain.com" did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY)
[2020/12/16 11:59:00.312383,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1775(main)
  smbd version 4.11.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2019
[2020/12/16 11:59:00.314300,  0] ../../source3/passdb/secrets.c:364(fetch_ldap_pw)
  fetch_ldap_pw: neither ldap secret retrieved!
[2020/12/16 11:59:00.314376,  0] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:6653(pdb_init_ldapsam_common)
  pdb_init_ldapsam_common: Failed to retrieve LDAP password from secrets.tdb
[2020/12/16 11:59:00.314397,  0] ../../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:179(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ldapsam:"ldap://domain.com" did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY)
[2020/12/16 12:06:22.284853,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:1775(main)
  smbd version 4.11.6-Ubuntu started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2019
[2020/12/16 12:06:22.295245,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1384(make_new_session_info_guest)
  create_local_token failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_MIX
[2020/12/16 12:06:22.295361,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:2034(main)
  ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
```

Config file (first time)

```
[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
    workgroup = domain
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://domain.com"
    realm = domain.com
```

Config file 2nd time

```
## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    realm = domain.com
    security = ads
```

Test share

```
[test]
    comment = test
    path = /test/
    browsable = yes
    valid users = +"HOME\Domain Users"
```

Comment: First, 'apt purge sssd' , you cannot use sssd with Samba >= 4.8.0, next, go and read this: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member